# Porting from GAE to TomCat or another servlet server

Tags: google-app-engine, tomcat, servlets

I'm unhappy from GAE because
  - One can't have a global variable and the 'synchronize' keyword. Instead one have to catch a basically DB transcational exception and retry in a while loop - which will eat all my free CPU time and will start costing me money as I reach the google's qouata.

1. Is it safe to use synchronize inside a doPost() in tomcat? (i guess that it's ok as long as all the servlets are running on on 1 VM?). If not in all tomcat configurations, how do I configure tomcat to make it safe?

How can I convert a GAE app to my own tomcat server?
 - How to install DataNucleus Access Platform on tomcat?

Best regards

Comment: The requirement makes no sense. Your problem lies somewhere else. Please elaborate about the problem in detail.

Comment: Ah I already see, you posted several similar/related questions about the subject, such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556644/google-app-engine-atomic-section The posted answer is very good. Think once about it again.

Answer (score 2):

App Engine is fundamentally a distributed system. You can't use synchronization primitives, because your app will be running on muliple VMs and multiple machines. Relying on running on a single VM will put very hard limits on the scalability of your app.

Why do you want to do this? There's almost certainly a way to achieve it without locking.

Comment: thanks for asking. Say a user is asking for the best fit free resource. We need to sync it so two users won't be allocated with the same resource.
I know we can use db transaction and if exception is thrown then we retrie in a loop but this solution waste the cpu and db. It's like not using sleep command and instead looping for nothing waisting cpu time...

Comment: Just assume that the algo for finding 'best fit' is expensive - then the problem is more concrete

Comment: As I've already said, it only 'loops' if there's a conflict. The vast majority of the time, there won't be contention, so it will execute fine the first time. And as others have said, optimistic concurrency is a common and valid approach to this, when contention is low.